# How to pass Ruby instance variable in a Python argument

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a Rails app that receives CSV files that are processed in Python. I was doing some simple tests and managed to execute a Python script within my Rails app and output the result in the browser.

Now, I want to pass the CSV file that is uploaded on the rails app, as an argument for my Python script.

Here is what I tried for the moment:

**upload_excel_controller.rb**

```
require 'json'

class UploadExcelController < ApplicationController
    require 'csv'

    def index
    end

    def import
      rowarray = Array.new
      myfile = params[:file]

      @rowarraydisp = CSV.read(myfile.path)
      @result = JSON.parse(`python lib/assets/python_scripts/python_test.py @rowarraydisp`)
    end
end
```

**python_test.py**

```
import json, sys

arg = sys.argv[1]

def main():
    return(arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    json.dump(main(), sys.stdout)
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag({:action => :import}, multipart: true) do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file %>
    <%= submit_tag( "Import" ) %>
<% end %>
```

**import.html.erb**

```
<% @result.each do |substring| %>
    <%= substring %>
    <p>End of this string, check next line for the other one!
<% end %>

<p>End of script</p>
```

When I run this, I get this error: `undefined method 'each' for "@rowarraydisp":String`.

It seems that `@rowarraydisp` was passed as a string.

Comment: What's the backtrace of your error?

Comment: Have you already tried simple string interpolation? `\`python script.py #{variable}\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
%x[python lib/assets/python_scripts/python_test.py #{@rowarraydisp}]
```

Comment: What happens when `@rowarraydisp` contains something that the shell will interpret?